# ajax call with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an ajax call after every 1 min but the succeeding call should be made only after the preceding ajax call was completed. For example ajax call 2 should be made only after ajax call 1 is completed.
I know how to make a function execute every 1 min with setInterval.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(function repeatAjaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "example-url.com",
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(repeatAjaxCall, 60000)
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the Underscore js debounce function?

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Basically, these allow you to call a "debounced" version of the function that will not be called until x number of milliseconds since the last call.

This will allow you to do something like this:

```
var update = _.debounce(function() {
    // do some ajax stuff here
}, 300);
setTimeout(update, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function ajaxCall(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $.get( url, function(data){
         // do stuff
         ajaxCall();
      })
   }, 60000)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying. If the next call will be fired just when the previous one has finished. And the previous one can delay more than 1 minutes. Let's supose, 2 minutes. So the next one will be called at least within 2 minutes delay. So knowing that. It's ok that will never work minute by minute, right?

So why not call the next ajax when the last one is completed, instead of fire it minute after minute? Using the complete method:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'file',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {},
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {

    //CALL HERE THE NEXT AJAX

},
```

Or if want to give a time of 1 minute after the the previous one is completed:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'file',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {},
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {

    setTimeout(function(){
       //CALL HERE THE NEXT AJAX
    }, 1000)

},
```

Comment: Should be 60000 rather than 1000

Comment: i have an ajax function which fetches number of messages the user has not read or arrival of new messages from the database. So i would like to make ajax call every 1 min to check for new messages. But if the last ajax call takes more than 1 min to complete, i would have another ajax call since ajax call are asynchronous. so ajax call would have interval of 1 min to execute and the last ajax call should be completed, if not wait for it to complete.

Comment: Got it. And my second idea with setTimeout after the ajax is completed doesn't fit to your scenario?